# Code is not executed even after if condition is true

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Can some one explain why this is happening? In the following code, even though the condition is returning true, the code in the `if` condition is not executed.

```
//suspend thread 
if (objThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
{
    objThread.Suspend();
}
```

Okay so this my scenario. I have two `TabItem`s. In `Window_Loaded` event, I start a thread which updates values to a `DataGrid` continuously. Now when I select the other `TabItem`, I want the updating in the first `TabItem` to stop. So, I put the above code in `TabItem_LostFocus` event. The thread should be suspended when the focus is lost, right? In the `UserControl_Loaded` event, I am checking for the state of the thread.

```
if (objThread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Suspended)
{
    objThread.Resume();
}
else
{
    // Start the thread
    objThread.Start();
}
```

But, I get an Error like this:
"Thread is running or terminated; it cannot restart."

But the thread is alive, because my UI is still being updated.

Comment: How did you verify this? The condition may very well be `true` when you test it, then subsequently `false` by the time you reach the `if` statement.

Comment: The number of times you should use `Thread.Suspend` is **staggeringly** small; the warning that appears in your build output is not just for giggles: `[ObsoleteAttribute("Thread.Suspend has been deprecated.  Please use other classes in System.Threading, such as Monitor, Mutex, Event, and Semaphore, to synchronize Threads or protect resources.  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202", false)]`

Comment: `Thread.Suspend()` method is obsolete. You can use [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx), [Thread.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/23f7b1ct(v=vs.110).aspx) or just `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: I receive data over the network continuously. So, to simulate the data receiving, I commented out the actual code and add a variable which is incremented in a loop. So, the thread is always running right?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Yes, I did read the warning in the build output. It is only for testing the functionality that I used `Thread.Suspend()`. It's going be different later. But, I wanted to know why.

Comment: if the `if` condition resolves true, then the code inside the `if` block is going to be executed. Frankly, I suspect that this is actually a timing issue, and it *isn't* `true` at the point of being evaluated - **or**, there's an outside chance that the project hasn't successfully built since adding the code, and you are actually debugging against an old version (it does happen occasionally)

Comment: You've discovered what's commonly known as a [race condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition).